# How to pass a simple string in to a Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a complex job flow where I have 3 separate jobs built into a JobStep, and then I call that JobStep from a Job. There will be four of these JobSteps that will run in parallel from the calling job.

I need to pass a string in to them as a parameter.

Somewhat simplified code:

My main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
}
```

One of the JobSteps looks like

```
@Bean
public JobStep jobStep1(<snip>){
        <snip for clarity>
        JobStep jobStep = new JobStep() ;
        jobStep.setJob(jobs.get(jobName)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .start(Flow1)
                .next(Flow2)
                .next(Flow3)
                .end().build());
        jobStep.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobStep.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        return jobStep; 
 }
```

The top job that runs the rest looks like

```
@Bean
    public Job parentJob(<snip>) {

        Flow childJobFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("childJob").start(job1).build();
        Flow childJobFlow2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("childJob2").start(job2).build();

        FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> builder = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("jobFlow");
        Flow jobFLow = builder.split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(childJobFlow,childJobFlow2).build();

        return jobs.get("parentJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .start(jobFLow)             
                .end().build();

    }
```

I need each JobStep to get a different string.

Comment: Please take a look on Partitioner. You can use it to pass data to Step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish as Nghia Do suggested in his comment by using Partitioner. With partitioner I was able to push a string on to the context and then in a @Before Step retrieve it.

In my ItemReader I have:

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) throws Exception {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    this.keyString =  stepExecution.getString("keyString");
}
```

The Paritioner

```
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    List<String> codes = getCodes();

    for (String code : codes)
    {
        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        context.put("keyString", code);
        partitionMap.put(code, context);
    }
    return partitionMap;
}
```

getCodes is just a placeholder function right now that returns a list of strings for testing. Eventually it will be replaces with something more useful.

```
private List<String> getCodes() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add("One");
        result.add("Two");  
        result.add("Three");    
        result.add("Four"); 
        result.add("Five"); 
        result.add("Six");
        result.add("Seven");
        return result;
    }
```

Then to get the steps I had make a master step that called my existing steps:

```
@Bean
    public Step masterStep(@Value("#{proccessFilesStep}") Step readFilesStep) {

        return  stepBuilders.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner(readFilesStep)
                .partitioner("proccessFilesStep", partitioner())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();

    }
```

And stepBuilders is:

```
@Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;
```

Had to combine like 20 different examples on the net to get all the peices so I am putting them all in this answer for the next person that needs it.